# React Progress Bar - Add additional class on individual bar when count is greater than 100

Tags: javascript, reactjs, progress-bar

I am trying to add additional class on respective progress bar only if count is greater than 100. But currently the additional class is applying to all progress bars instead of individual one.I have handleProgressBar click handler which is responsible for progress bar count. Below is my code on codesandbox, or maybe someone will give me some hints as to what to edit in my code make if functional.   https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-lake-ed6s2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the sample with array of barAdditionalClass:
https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-tree-q8y24

Comment: Great. Really appreciate your help.